# How to scroll automatically, if a page is clicked from a link

Tags: jquery, scroll, click, global-variables

I want to make a page scroll-down with jQuery, but only if there's a click on a link to this page from another page. Both pages are in the same directory.

This is the code for the page to be scrolled:

```
var trigger;
$(document).ready(function(){
if (trigger == 'on') {
$('html, body').not('#jens').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('#geschaeftsstelle').offset().top)
    }, 500, 'swing' );
    } else {
        return false};
    });
```

But now, I don't know how to change 'trigger', if a clickevent on the linked page happens:

```
$('#kontakt').click(function(){
trigger = 'on';
};
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (window.location.hash) {
    $('html, body').not('#jens').animate({
        scrollTop: ($(window.location.hash).offset().top)
    }, 500, 'swing' );
    } else {
        return false
    };
 });
```

don't forget to use simple links like `href="path-to-your-page.html#geschaeftsstelle"` and no `smth.click()`

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem here still is that once you have clicked on the # link, it jumps directly to the # and can't scroll to it. As there's no event, you can't use preventDefault either. To make it work nevertheless, I refer to a new #anchor at the top of the page and then scroll down to where I actually want to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a simple variable and declare it global or something like that, as all of that will be overwritten on page load. But you could:

1. Set a cookie, and react to to that on the page you want to scroll on (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)
2. If you control the other link, you could change it accordingly. One nice option could be to set an anchor, then it would automatically go to its position. Or you could set a parameter and get that from window.location.pathname

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.referrer` to check `referrer url` from another page

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.referrer.indexOf('url-you-want-test') !== -1) { // replace url-you-want-test with url you want to test abosulte url or file-name
        $('html, body').not('#jens').animate({
            scrollTop: ($('#geschaeftsstelle').offset().top)
        }, 500, 'swing');
    }
});
```